# Pandas: return feature names if variable is true

Tags: python, string, pandas, boolean, filtering

I have a list of ~2M strings and a list of ~800 words. I have created a dataframe with strings as rows and words as columns. With the exception of the string variable, all of the other variables are true or false values corresponding to whether or not the word is in the string. There are no missing values.

i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'strings':['a string with california', 
                              'a string with lobster', 
                              'a str with california and lobster'],
                         'california':[True,False,True],
                         'lobster':[False,True,True],
                         'string':[True,True,False],})
```

Because the dataframe is too long and wide to view at once, I would like to have a variable that lists the column names that have a true value for that particular row. For example,

```
df_filtered = pd.DataFrame({'strings':['a string with california', 
                              'a string with lobster', 
                              'a str with california and lobster'],
                   'matches':[['string','california'],
                              ['string', 'lobster'],
                              ['california', 'lobster']],
                         'california':[True,False,True],
                         'lobster':[False,True,True],
                         'string':[True,True,False],})
```

I am new to pandas and have figured out that I can create a list of column names with missing values with the following command

```
columns_w_na = df.columns[df.isnull().any()].tolist()
```

Is there a way that I can, for each row, similarly capture the names of columns with a particular value and represent it at as a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the responses above does a good job of creating a bracketed string of the matches separated by commas which is really helpful. I had a subsequent issue where I needed to count the number of matched phrases which made it more helpful to have the column in a list type as opposed to a string.

```
df['matches'] = df.eq(True).dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1].str.split(',')
df['num_matches'] = df['matches'].str.len()
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check

```
df.eq(True).dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1].str.split()
0     [california,string]
1        [lobster,string]
2    [california,lobster]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, both responses were very helpful. Your response was especially scalable

Comment: @JackReimer yw : -) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

use `apply` with a lambda expression:

```
# setting axis=1 in apply means you are looking across rows
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.columns[x == True].values, axis=1)

                             strings  california  lobster  string  \
0           a string with california        True    False    True   
1              a string with lobster       False     True    True   
2  a str with california and lobster        True     True   False   

                     new  
0   [california, string]  
1      [lobster, string]  
2  [california, lobster]
```